# Why would a VB6 .frm file ever be full of binary?

Tags: vb6, frm

I am sorting out some `.frm` files in a VB6 project.  I have found some of them are full of binary data.  Clearly these wouldn't compile and I discovered that they are not being referenced by the project but are just sitting in the project folder doing nothing.

Why would `.frm` files end up having binary data in them?

Note: These are definitley `.frm` files. I know that the `.frx` files contain binary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VB3/VB4 used a binary form/code file. Either that or they're just corrupt.
You can probably confirm with the modified date.

Comment: If it was saved as binary in an earlier version and you have access to that version you can open the form change the save option to save it as text.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this a few years ago when some of the frm files became corrupt (this happened in a live project and the IDE failed to load the files) - Opening them in wordpad showed all non-printable characters.

I would say that if they are not being referenced then they should be safe to remove.